# Yellow normals instead of blue, compositing.how to turn it blue

Tags: compositing-nodes

i have trying to do a normal map from a ocean modified plane, but can´t get a blue normal map put of it. i used [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVB3Zto6X5o&list=PLBSVQqzB6k6Wl10BNgdrLO7XmCP6jLdP5&index=11)

this video to build the setting and think i have done everything that is mentioned on the video but when i render the normals are yellow and not blue . i try to render an animation sequence so baking
is not a option because it would be so slow. is there anything i could try to get it to normal blue color output, i have tried to flip and switch the direction of normals but that does not seem to work.[image]

Comment: I’d say it’s that invert color node at the end of the compositing tree. Delete that node and everything should work normally, as it were.

Comment: that worked, why it was in the instructional video i have no idea. deleted it now its blue.